# Save user data in UserProfile with Middleware and GeoIP

Tags: python, django

I have a small question to ask you. I use GEO IP to locate my users and I would like to record this information every time user log in to improve the user experience of the app. The problem is that it doesn't save absolutely nothing at each connection. UserProfile models is empty...

Anyone has an idea about this?

user/middleware.py

```
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class LastLoginInfo(MiddlewareMixin):
  def geolocalisation(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        
        device_type = ""
        browser_type = ""
        browser_version = ""
        os_type = ""
        os_version = ""
        
        if request.user_agent.is_mobile:
            device_type = "Mobile"
        if request.user_agent.is_tablet:
            device_type = "Tablet"
        if request.user_agent.is_pc:
            device_type = "PC"
        
        browser_type = request.user_agent.browser.family
        browser_version = request.user_agent.browser.version_string
        os_type = request.user_agent.os.family
        os_version = request.user_agent.os.version_string
        
        g = GeoIP2()
        location = g.city(ip)
        location_country = location["country_name"]
        location_city = location["city"]
        
        #UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=request.user, defaults={'ip_address_ua': request.data['ip']})
        UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user.pk).update(ip_address_ua=ip, device_ua=device_type, browser_ua=browser_type, os_device_ua=os_version, city_ua=location_city, country_ua=location_country)
```

main/settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'user.middleware.LastLoginInfo',
    ...

]
```

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: This implementation, even when fixed, is terrible for performance reasons. You're essentially causing one extra DB query per request to find the user object (despite already having it in `request.user`), then another update, regardless of whether the user's location has changed. I suggest you skip querying for the user because you already have it in `request.user`, and check whether any of its location parameters are different from the current request before updating. Finally, I think updating user objects in request middleware is bad practice either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make some changes :)

```
class LastLoginInfo(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your method is missing the `self` parameter.

```py
def process_request(self, request):
```

If this does not resolve the issue, then I believe the issue here is the ordering of your middleware:

You should ensure that your middleware is listed AFTER any authentication middleware.

Otherwise, this statement will never catch

```
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

For example, if you use `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`, you need the following:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'
    'user.middleware.LastLoginInfo', # this must come AFTER auth middleware
    ...

]
```

Comment: Do you mean this:
class LastLoginInfo(MiddlewareMixin):
    def geolocalisation(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():

Or this:

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    class LastLoginInfo(MiddlewareMixin):
            def geolocalisation(request):

Comment: Tried adding some more clarification to the question @Beginner

Comment: I've edited my question with your correction I guess but nothing is saved when I log in after logging out. Is my code wrong?

Comment: Yes for the middleware that I've done :) but nothing change. I'v try to save the last login time and it works but I don't understand that does not work with this code

Comment: Thanks for you help @sytech the solution is found

Comment: ah I see. The issue was an error in the method signature. Glad you found this.